# App reads my Apple ID

Tags: ios, apple-id

I am interested to know, can an app read my Apple ID?

Here is my issue: I have outsourced my app to a company. The app is a social networking app: you create a profile and insert few profile details: name, age, gender. However it does not relay on phone numbers like Whats App, email addresses or Facebook profiles.

The App is now live in the App store and I have my Ipad and Iphone registered on the same Apple Id. I have downloaded the app on my phone and created a profile. Now I have downloaded it on the iPad as well and I am seeing the same profile I created on my phone.

I've have tried other apps that use a similar logic, no phone numbers, emails or FB profiles (Whisper App being one of them) and I can create 2 different profiles one on the phone and the other on the iPad. So I am wondering if the problem surfaces because there is something in the code that makes the app read my Apple ID.

I would really appreciate your help

Comment: No, there is no API allowing a 3rd party app to access any details about a user's iTunes account or Apple ID.

Comment: What is the app called?

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. WMios the app is called Happer. Please let me know if you download it and you experience the same issue. Would greatly appreciate it since I have to sort this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't provide an API allowing an application to read information about the user's Apple ID. This helps protect the identity of the user, I personally don't want *any* third-party app reading information about my Apple ID.

Comment: Hi Undo that you for your answer. I thought so but wanted to double check. As mentioned the app has been already approved by the App Store and I do not think they would have approved an app that can read your Apple ID.